# Criar bloqueio temporário no aplicativo

Tags: android

No app que estou desenvolvendo existe uma política de uso, e caso essa política seja burlada quero suspender o uso do app por 30 mins, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Toda activity passa pelo método onCreate. Uma solução que consigo imaginar é só fazer uma simples validação verificando se o usuário fez algo de errado. Caso tenha feito, você pode chamar uma Intent que manda para uma outra activity que informa que ele foi bloqueado e quanto tempo falta

Answer (score 10):

Tem de implementar algo que permita à aplicação saber se está bloqueada ou não.

Essa informação pode, como disse o regmoraes, ser guardada na *Shared Preferences*.

A questão que se põe agora é como saber que passaram 30 minutos de forma a desbloqueá-la.

Uma solução seria guardar, não uma *flag*(true/false), mas o valor em milissegundos da data(*timestamp*) em que a aplicação foi bloqueada.
Para verificar se passaram 30 minutos é só fazer a subtracção entre a data actual e a data gravada.

Método para bloquear:

```
private void block(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences("Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putLong("BlockTime", new Date().getTime());
    editor.commit();
}
```

Método para verificar se está bloqueado:

```
private boolean isBlocked(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences("Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    long blockTime = sharedPref.getLong("BlockTime", 0);
    return new Date().getTime() - blockTime < 1800000; //30*60*1000
}
```

**EDIT:**

Pode evitar que o sistema seja ludibriado pelo utilizador, se este alterar a data/hora do sistema, da seguinte forma:

Além de guardar o *timestamp* guarde também uma *flag* que indica se está bloqueado ou não:

```
private void block(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences("Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putLong("BlockTime", new Date().getTime());
    editor.putBoolean("IsBlocked", true);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Declare um *BroadcastReceiver* que responda à acção `android.intent.action.TIME_SET`. Ele será chamado quando houver uma alteração da data/hora do sistema:

**TimeChangeReceiver.java**

```
public class TimeChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //Houve uma alteração na data/hora do sistema
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences("Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isBlocked = sharedPref.getBoolean("IsBlocked", false);
        if(isBlocked){
            //Grava novo timestamp
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putLong("BlockTime", new Date().getTime());
            editor.commit();
        }
    }    
}
```

Registe o *receiver* no *AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<receiver android:name=".TimeChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Altere o método `isBlocked()` para lidar com a *flag*:

```
private boolean isBlocked(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences("Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    long blockTime = sharedPref.getLong("BlockTime", 0);
    boolean isBlocked = new Date().getTime() - blockTime < 1800000; //30*60*1000
    if(!isBlocked){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("IsBlocked", false);
        editor.commit();
    }
    return isBlocked
}
```

Chame o método `isBlocked()` no `onResesume()`

A minha única dúvida é se pequenas alterações da hora devido às sincronizações automáticas(caso estejam ligadas) irão ou não lançar o *Receiver*

Comment: Mesmo assim, usuário mal intencionado vai alterar a data do dispositivo para ser desbloqueado! Se o aplicativo tiver conexão com a internet seria interessante a Data se obtida da internet, ou até mesmo que o bloqueio seja feito no servidor! Usuário mal intencionado ("os espertinhos") é o que não falta!

Comment: Bem colocado Fernando

Comment: @Fernado Você tem razão, haverá sempre um modo de ultrapassar qualquer que seja a protecção, umas mais dificilmente do que outras.

Comment: Acho valido fazer o teste em caso de troca de horários automáticos, talvez gera algum problema, mas em geral, é uma ótima solução.

Comment: @PauloGustavo No caso de estar desbloqueado não tem problema, no caso de estar bloqueado irá renovar o bloqueio por mais 30 minutos.

Comment: Se eu quiser criar uma cota, tipo por dia você pode burlar a regra até duas vezes, seria mais um dado salvo no shared prefferences?

Comment: Sim, isso deve ser feito no método `block()`

Answer (score 5):

A solução que o @PauloGustavo deu nos comentários é uma boa saída, mas eu faria uma pequena alteração:

É melhor você fazer a validação no método `onResume()` da activity, pois esse método **sempre é chamado** quando se abre uma activity, mesma que ela tenha sido apenas *pausada*. Já o `onCreate()` só é chamado uma vez ( quando a Activity é criada ), portanto, um usuário "malandro" poderia "burlar" a verificação da seguinte maneira:

1. O usuário fere a política de uso
2. O app trava
3. O usuário sai do app colocando-o em segundo plano ( apertando a tecla home, por exemplo)
4. O usuário abre a lista de apps recentes e escolhe o seu app
5. O usuário volta a mexer no seu app normalmente!

Isso acontece pois nessa ida e volta, a sua activity não foi destruída, foi apenas parada, isso significa que quando você abrí-la de novo, o método `onCreate()` não será chamado

Uma outra dica que eu dou é:

- Guarde uma variável que indique que o app está bloqueado numa [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Assim, quando o usuário ferir a política de uso, você faz isso na sua activity:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.bloqueado), true);
editor.commit();
```

Se você quiser "desbloquear" o app, basta escrever o mesmo código acima, trocando `true` por `false`.

Para tratar a condição de "app bloqueado" ou não, coloque o seguinte código no método `onResume()` da sua Activity:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean bloqueado = sharedPref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.bloqueado), /* valor default*/ );

if(bloqueado){

    //Notifica o usuário ou fecha a Activity

}else{

   //Continue a execução da Activity normalmente
}
```

Comment: Muito bom. Acrescento aqui um link que mostra o ciclo de vida da atividade para melhor compreensão: http://www.devmedia.com.br/imagens/articles/263421/Activity.png

Comment: Só falta explicar como fazer para o aplicativo ficar desbloqueado após terem passado os 30 minutos.

Comment: @ramaral editei a resposta adicionando uma explicação para isso

Comment: O problema não é escrever `true` na *Shared Preferences* mas sim fazê-lo passados 30 minutos. Desculpe os meus comentários mas julgo que a resposta só atenderá completamente à pergunta se isso for explicado.

Comment: Valeu meu velho, basicamente eu tinha pensado nisso mesmo, usando o sharedpreferences, mas meu problema maior é com o tempo, como programar para desbloquear o app automaticamente?

Comment: Exato @ramaral o maior problema por minha parte, é a parte do agendamento dos 30 min.

Comment: Você pode criar um service, que ira executar em background durante um tempo e sem depender que a aplicação esteja aberta. Visto isso, você pode criar um serviço para fazer tal desbloqueio e/ou quando a pessoa abrir a aplicação você ver quanto tempo falta. 
http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 1):

Como fazer o bloqueio já foi respondido, a dúvida agora esta em como desbloquear. Acho que fazer um [serviço](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/components/services.html) background seria a boa solução.

Como o @ramaral sugeriu e o @Fernando comentou, o bloqueio por meio de tempo seria algo burlável e exigir que o APP tenha conexão com internet também é muito arriscado vendo que esse nunca possa mais ter após o bloqueio e caso isso aconteça, nunca terá um desbloqueio.

Acredito que criando um serviço podemos obter o resultado do bloqueio sem que o usuário consiga burlar.

Crie um service como algo parecido com isso:

```
    public class MyService extends Service {

    private Timer timer;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 2000, 5000); //2000 representa o tempo da primeira chamada e 5000 das demais (milissegundos)
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

private TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //do something

                    // stopSelf()
                }
            });

        }
    };


    }
```

O problema dessa abordagem é que se o aparelho for desligado, o serviço será perdido. Caso isso aconteça, você provavelmente terá que implementar para que o serviço inicie novamente no boot do aparelho.

Comment: Inicialmente tinha pensado numa solução que usava um *Timer* para lançar um *BroadcastReceiver* que desbloquearia a aplicação. O problema era o mesmo da sua solução: caso o aparelho fosse desligado, durante esse periodo, a aplicação ficaria sempre bloqueada. Tal podia ser resolvido por um novo BroadcastReceiver a ser lançado no boot. Achei que a solução seria complicada. Como ambas podem ser "ludibriadas"  recorrendo à alteração da data do sistema optei por aquela que é mais simples.