# Controllar a sessão no android

Tags: java, android

Eu estou usando o SharedPreferences para gerar uma sessão no android.
Eu queria fazer uma verificação que, após um tempo (5 minutos por exemplo), ele dar um timeout, zerar essa sessão e redirecionar para o Login.
É possivel fazer isso usando o SharedPreferences?

Comment: Sim é possível. Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126378/2541), não é a mesma coisa mas os princípios a aplicar são os mesmos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde,

pode ser utilizado normalmente, mas tens que prestar atenção a real necessidade de usar isto. Caso tua aplicação se comunique com algum webApi, seria mais interessante guardar esta conexão lá.